# How to lighten BMP image using C++

Tags: c++, windows, image-processing, bitmap, bmp

I'd like to lighten a bitmap from `input_file.bmp` using C++ code. The image is saved using Windows Paint as `256 Colour Bitmap (*.bmp;*.dib)`. I tried to add **1** to every color from every pixel using the code below to lighten it a little bit:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const int CHARS_PER_PIXEL = 3;

int main() {
    ifstream inputStream("input_file.bmp", ios::binary); // Read the input
    if (!inputStream.good())
        return 1;

    char* temp = new char[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
    inputStream.read(temp, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    BITMAPFILEHEADER* FileInfo = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
    *FileInfo = *(BITMAPFILEHEADER*)(temp);

    temp = new char[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];
    inputStream.read(temp, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* PictureInfo = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    *PictureInfo = *(BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(temp);
    delete temp;

    int charsNumber = CHARS_PER_PIXEL * PictureInfo->biHeight * PictureInfo->biWidth;
    unsigned char* arrayOfChars = new unsigned char[charsNumber];
    inputStream.read((char*)arrayOfChars, charsNumber * sizeof(char));
    inputStream.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < charsNumber; i++) // The actual color change
        arrayOfChars[i] = arrayOfChars[i] + 1 > 255 ? 255 : arrayOfChars[i] + 1;

    ofstream outputStream("output_file.bmp", ios::binary); // Save the output
    if (!outputStream.good()) {
        delete FileInfo;
        delete PictureInfo;
        delete arrayOfChars;
        return 1;
    }

    outputStream.write((char*)FileInfo, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    outputStream.write((char*)PictureInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    outputStream.write((char*)arrayOfChars, charsNumber * sizeof(char));
    outputStream.close();

    delete FileInfo;
    delete PictureInfo;
    delete arrayOfChars;
    return 0;
}
```

The code reads a bitmap file, reads bitmap headers using structures provided in `Windows.h` library, adds **1** value to every color for every pixel and saves all of it in the output file.

The code produces an image presented below:

[image: Input and output images]

The generated image (the right one) is not lightened but modified in some different way. How could I fix my mistake?

*EDIT:*

While debugging I extracted values stored in the headers:

BITMAPFILEHEADER:

- bfType: 19778
- bfSize: 361078
- bfReserved1: 0
- bfReserved2: 0
- bfOffBits: 1078

BITMAPINFOHEADER:

- biSize: 40
- biWidth: 600
- biHeight: 600
- biPlanes: 1
- biBitCount: 8
- biCompression: 0
- biSizeImage: 36000
- biXPelsPerMeter: 0
- biYPelsPerMeter: 0
- biClrUsed: 0
- biClrImportant: 0

Comment: Does your bitmap contains color table? Do you use BI_BITFIELDS compression? Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader for more info.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric - the bitmap contains an image presented in the link. Here are values I extracted from the headers:
BITMAPFILEHEADER:
 - bfType: 19778
 - bfSize: 361078
 - bfReserved1: 0
 - bfReserved2: 0 
 - bfOffBits: 1078
BITMAPINFOHEADER:
 - biSize: 40
 - biWidth: 600
 - biHeight: 600
 - biPlanes: 1
 - biBitCount: 8
 **- biCompression: 0**
 - biSizeImage: 36000
 - biXPelsPerMeter: 0 
 - biYPelsPerMeter: 0
 - biClrUsed: 0 
 - biClrImportant: 0

Comment: _biBitCount: 8_ That looks like a palette based image. In this case, you shouldn't touch the pixel bytes but perform the lightening on the color table. Have a look at [Wikipedia: BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) for more insights.

Comment: Found this: _Color table ... Mandatory for color depths ≤ 8 bits_ and _the color table is normally not used when the pixels are in the 16-bit per pixel (16bpp) format (and higher); there are normally no color table entries in those bitmap image files._ So, in your case (with 8bpp), a color table is used.

Comment: This would explain the strange colors, you get in output. By adding 1 to all pixel values, you just shift the color through color table. However, there is no requirement that neighbour entries in color table have to represent similar colors. In your sample, this seems not to be the case -> resulting in this interesting but unintended effect.

Comment: But, the input image is really nice. ;-) I did something similar when I was a schoolboy (with paper and brush), and it still hangs on the wall in my parents home.

Comment: @Scheff - thanks a lot! This absolutely solves my problem. The easiest way I found is to change the input image format to `24-bit Bitmap (*.bmp;*.dib)` in the Paint. That will be my MVP. Maybe after all I will refactor it to work correctly also with `256 Colour Bitmap (*.bmp;*.dib)` ones. Thanks again!
I also like this image! But in this case it's not mine. I found it [here](https://www.partow.net/programming/bitmap/index.html) ;)

Comment: You have 5 `new` operators and 3 `delete` operators, that's a memory leak. Just declare `BITMAPFILEHEADER FileInfo;` then read it as `inputStream.read((char*)&FileInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));` You only need one `new` allocation for `arrayOfChars`, followed by one `delete`. You can also use `std::vector` to avoid keeping track of memory allocation.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks for pointing it! In the real implementation for sure I'll take care of it ;) This time I just wanted to provide a minimal example of my problem

Comment: Sure. By the way, Windows provides `Gdiplus` which can handle changing brightness level and similar operations. Or you may use other libraries instead of this low level programming.